# Create index for Join some table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, indexing

I have SQL query for MySQL database bellow:

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS count,
    sum(total) AS total
FROM
    vtiger_salesorder
INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid
INNER JOIN vtiger_sobillads ON vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_sobillads.sobilladdressid
INNER JOIN vtiger_soshipads ON vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_soshipads.soshipaddressid
INNER JOIN vtiger_salesordercf ON vtiger_salesordercf.salesorderid = vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid
INNER JOIN vtiger_account ON vtiger_account.accountid = vtiger_salesorder.accountid
LEFT JOIN vtiger_users ON vtiger_users.id = vtiger_salesordercf.cf_456
LEFT JOIN vtiger_contactdetails ON vtiger_salesorder.contactid = vtiger_contactdetails.contactid
LEFT JOIN vtiger_soshop ON vtiger_soshop.salesorderid = vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid
WHERE
    vtiger_crmentity.deleted = 0
ORDER BY
    vtiger_crmentity.modifiedtime DESC;
```

[Please click here to show Explain above SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAahw.png)

Could you help me create some index to improve performance for this query.
Thanks

Comment: You need indexes on field that are used to filter or order your data.

Comment: Please edit your question an add the DDL for the tables including indexes and the execution plan of your query.

Comment: Hi @stickybit, I added image of Explain that SQL.

Comment: What is being SUMed???

Answer (score 0):

You can try if the following three compound indexes bring any improvement.

```
CREATE INDEX idxCrmidDeleted
             ON vtiger_crmentity
                (crmid,
                 deleted);

CREATE INDEX idxSalesorderidAccountidContactid
             ON vtiger_salesorder
                (salesorderid,
                 accountid,
                 contactid);

CREATE INDEX idxSalesorderidCf_456
             ON vtiger_salesordercf
                (salesorderid,
                 cf_456);
```

Check the execution plan if they are taken.

And where does the column `total` come from? If it is from any of the tables the indexes above go on, also try an index like the above but additionally with `total` as the last column. E.g.

```
CREATE INDEX idxSalesorderidAccountidContactid
             ON vtiger_salesorder
                (salesorderid,
                 accountid,
                 contactid,
                 total);
```

if `total` is in `vtiger_salesorder`. Then there is a chance only the index is queried alone.

Answer (score 0):

These indexes may help:

```
crmentity:   (deleted, modifiedtime)  -- in this order
salesorder:  (salesorderid)
```

But...

- If all the `JOINs` are 1:1, you only need the table with `total` in it.
- If some of the `JOINs` are 1:many`, then`COUNT(*)`and/or`SUM(total)` will get inflated values!